# Having trouble selecting target after firing custom JS trigger

Tags: jquery, triggers, target, siblings

Here is the general layout of the trigger and target.

```
<div id="search">
    <form id="searchForm"></form>
</div>
<div class="searchResults"></div>
```

After the user inputs a search term, the searchResults div gets populated like so:

```
<div class="searchResults">

<ul>

    <li>Result One</li>
    <li>Result Two</li>
    <li>Result Three</li>

</ul>

</div>
```

The trigger is set up like so:

```
    $('#searchForm').trigger('search.categories.updated');
```

I have then created this simple script to try and fire an alert when the user clicks on one of the dynamically generated search results:

```
    $(document).on('search.categories.updated', function(e){

                var target = $(e.target),

                 searchtarget = target.find('.searchResults + ul li a');


                searchtarget.click(function() {

                    alert("yay it works!");

                    });

            });
```

Unfortunately this is not working.  I believe that it has to do with the `searchtarget` variable improperly targeting the sibiling `div`.  Any idears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`searchtarget` variable is set incorrectly, yes. It should be:

```
searchtarget = $('.searchResults ul li');
```

(searching for `li` inside `ul` inside `.searchResults`).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5n2f5ksh/1/).

Comment: thanks, this looks good.  I just updated the question with a more correct form and div relationship as this answer is not working for my site for some reason.  I will test it with the fiddle to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: well your fiddle still works with my update.. not sure why I am still having trouble on the site.

Comment: @Presto did you wrap your code with `$(document).ready`? I forgot to mention this moment in fiddle. Take a look at [updated one](http://jsfiddle.net/5n2f5ksh/1/).

Comment: yeah I did. I have found a solution based upon your suggestions, so I am awarding. Thanks.